# The user types in "he is ok", how do I should print out 3 words and 9 letters instead of printing it out multiple times with different values?

Tags: mips

This program gets the user to input a sentence and it will count the number of words and letters and displays the result. The user will be asked to input a sentence again until he/she enters a blank string or hit cancel

```
    .data
wordCount:      .word       0       
letterCount:        .word       0
userInput:      .space          100             
messagePrompt:      .asciiz     "Enter a short sentence" 
messageWords:       .asciiz     "Words"
messageLetters:     .asciiz     "characters\n"
messageGoodBye:     .asciiz     "Goodbye!"      
            

.text 

mainLoop:   # use the dialog syscall (#54) to input a string from the user
# pops up a display box for the user 
la $a0, messagePrompt
la $a1, userInput
la $a2, 200
li $v0, 54          
syscall
 
StringCopy: #push the stack and save $s1
addi    $sp, $sp, -4    
sw  $s1, 0($sp)
move    $s1, $a0
jal WordsLoop   
    
Exit:       #display goodbye message dialog
la $a0, messageGoodBye
li $v0, 59
syscall
        
# End Program
li  $v0, 10
syscall 
    
WordsLoop:  #   if (y[i]== " " ) i++    
lbu $t2, 0($s1)
beqz    $t2, Print      #   $t2 = y[i]
beq $t2, $t3, LettersLoop   #   put Wordsloop later....     
addi    $s1, $s1, 1     #   i++
addi    $v0, $v0, 1     #   $t1 = addr of y[i] 
        
j   WordsLoop
        
LettersLoop:    #   if (y[i] != '\0')   return i++  
addi    $v0, $v0, 1     #   $t1 = addr of y[i] 
addi    $v1, $v1, 1     #   i = 0   
addi    $s1, $s1, 1     #   i++
        
j   WordsLoop
    
Print:  # outputs users input
    
addi    $v0, $v0, -1
sw  $v0, letterCount
addi    $v1, $v1, 1
sw  $v1, wordCount
    
blt     $a1, 0, Exit

la  $a0, userInput
li  $v0, 4
syscall
        
lw  $a0, letterCount
li  $v0, 1
syscall

la  $a0, 32     # Print space  
li  $v0, 11
syscall 

la  $a0, messageWords
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la  $a0, 32     # Print space  
li  $v0, 11
syscall 
    
lw  $a0, wordCount
li  $v0, 1
syscall

la  $a0, 32     # Print space  
li  $v0, 11
syscall 

la  $a0, messageLetters
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la  $a0, 32     # Print space  
li  $v0, 11
syscall 

#program ends
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Please note you haven’t asked a question or explained the problem. Please edit the question and explain what is wrong with the code exactly. For example, given input, desired output, what output you get instead

Comment: typo: "He is ok" is supposed to execute once and display 8 characters/letters, not 9.

Comment: My program is that my output printed multiple times. One of then has a huge number like "75 words and 1 character"